# Updating and displaying data simultaneously from loop in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

The data has to be shown in `QTableWidget` from a loop as soon as the loop variable is updated, where the loop is like:

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data.index))
for i in data.index:
  # do some operation
  self.tableWidget.setItem(i,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Entering row number: " + str(i+1)))
  self.tableWidget.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Processing.."))
  time.sleep(60)
  self.tableWidget.setItem(i,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Entering row number: " + str(i+1)))
  self.tableWidget.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Done"))
  # do some operation
```

where `data` is a dataframe. The data in the table gets displayed only after the complete execution of the loop, at once. But I want to display the data after each iteration of the loop. How to achieve this?

Comment: While GUI updates are possible while inserting data, it's not advisable to do that too often, as it might also result in decreased performance. The real question are: how is the variable updated, and how often? What is the (possible) amount of the data?

Comment: The variables will get updated every one minute and the amount of data can be 100+ lines.